# Firebase phone number verification not always sending sms

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a use case where I need each user to be identified by a phone number, this is because my shops will need to call the users who request an order , I have followed the documentation and all the github repo with the code

Actually the code worked, and sended to me the sms to verify and all worked just fine !

Now, before release, I have just plugged another phone, requested the code to verify and the code never arrived !

I just tried in another phone with another number and also the verification code has never reached that phone either.

But I actually verified a phone number with the actual code and it works, so, why is the code not reaching my users phone ?

My use case needs this feature and if this is on Firebase side I will need to move to another service

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can use the verification code you added with the test phone number on the console.
`Firebase Console Dashboard` -> `Authentication` -> `SignIn Method` -> `Phone` -> `Phone numbers for testing`.

Sometimes, firebase don't need to send the otp for confirmation. it can automatically be done.
This method is called in two situations:

- **Instant verification**: in some cases the phone number can be instantly verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
- **Auto-retrieval**: on some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action. (This capability might be unavailable with some carriers.)
  In either case, the user's phone number has been verified successfully, and you can use the PhoneAuthCredential object that's passed to the callback to sign in the user.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential

Check out the docs for Firebase Phone Verification for Android : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=1#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers

Comment: how do you know it works fine on production ? I dont want to go live and see how it crashes with real users, I have tested this in debug mode with a real device and the messages came in right, but now it does not arrive

Comment: Everything is mentioned in the docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=1#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers

Comment: Another option is to try a staging build, before the release.

Comment: Can you point me where I can see the part " works only in production ", thanks

Comment: Have you added SHA fingerprint of the app in the console settings?

Comment: Updated the `google-services.json` after adding it ?

Comment: Sometimes, firebase don't need to send the otp for confirmation. it can automatically be done.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential

Comment: I have updated the answer, apologies for the unverified info before.
The edited answer might be something you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I have already readed all the documentation before asking the question and tried several things, the problems are with the carriers